# how to block indent in codeblocks

Tags: codeblocks

consider the following code :

```
  int n,m,group=1;
  char ch;

            n=getint(); //WANT TO BACKWARD INDENT IT 
            m=getint();  //WANT TO BACK WARD INDENT IT

    if(m==10)
        ch='p';
    else
        ch='n';
...........
...........
```

So how would we do it in code blocks ? for forward indent , we select the block and press TAB key but what about backward especially in case when we have a large block of code?

Comment: Are you searching for `SHIFT-TAB` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Select the block :

if want to forward indent it use tab key ...
for backward use shift + tab key .....